# Why does Arduino get damaged when used in this relay circuit?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, relay

I am controlling a heating element using microcontroller development board (https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-nano?queryID=a777b4d5d5a1040ab95d2450172b4ef2) using the following circuit. It worked fine until I changed the pinMode(PIN#,OUTPUT) command in the code to turn the digital IO on which resulted in fumes from the microcontroller. Initially an internal pull up resistance is set in order to avoid short circuit. when pinMode() command is used to set the pin to output mode, the resistance is removed. So, I wonder if my following circuit has caused this?

The resistance of the heating element is very low, 15.8ohm, is this ok to attach the element in the following manner?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSEuBE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you really connect 12V to the Vin of the Arduino Nano?

Comment: Yes! and it worked for quite some time both with 12V and PC USB. I saw the output in the serialmonitor. Then I tried to put 2 more leds on D2 and D3 which didn't work because there wasn't pinMode(OUTPUT) in the code. However, when I used pinMode command, and connected to USB it gave fumes. I am not sure what went wrong there.

Comment: What is supplying the 12V? Are you using a genuine Arduino Nano, or a 'clone' (which one)? Please show us a photo of your setup, including all wiring.

Comment: Added thermister block in the circuit as well as images. Not sure if geniune but regulator on the board is AMS1117 if that is what you were thinking. Source is 12V wall adapter.

Comment: Looking at those pictures, you shouldn't be surprised that things burn up, this is all very sloppy and the soldering has not been done correctly. I'd toss this in the garbage and redo it properly from scratch. If you don't know how to assemble electronics then enlist someone who can.

Comment: You might have shorted R2 during soldering. Prove the setup on a breadboard before moving to PCB

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that schematic, at least nothing that would fry the MCU. I think it's most probable that you've simply wired something up wrong. I know that's not what you want to hear, but seriously, the circuit as you've drawn it here is not capable of damaging the MCU. There's something else going on that isn't drawn here.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason is that with a 12 V input, you're overloading the poor 5V regulator IC on your arduino board: even at benign currents, it has to dissipate (12 V - 5 V)•(current) in heat, and that IC is tiny.

Other than that: your heater draws less than an ampere. That's not a big load that you need a relay for; a slightly more generously sized general purpose npn transistor or logic level n-channel MOSFET would totally do, and remove the only "dangerous" part of this circuitry (the flyback voltage of the relay's coil). We can't guess from your description whether you're using an appropriate flyback diode, since you mentioned neither diode nor relay model, but seeing the relay is superfluous, well, get rid of it.

Comment: It isn't quite right. AMS1117 can handle upto 20V and in the end it wasn't regulator that got burned I guess because MCU wasn't functional. FTDI was functional. It is a 12V relay. Coil is running on a 12V and I am not sure how much is the current draw at 12V. Why remove the flyback diode?

Comment: BTW it is functioning alright with a new arduino board. The only difference is now I have put a diode at the Vin in order to stop the reverse current flow there. I noticed there were 3.5V at Vin when arduino was running on USB supply.

Comment: @azad.parinda mmmm wasn't suggesting to remove the flyback diode (that would not be a good idea) but to check that it's of acceptable quality.

Comment: I just checked the specs on the Arduino using the link given by the OP. It clearly states that Vin can range from 7V to 12V. If the system was built as drawn I don't see any excessive current draw from the Arduino itself.

Comment: At any rate, sounds unlikely that the LDO wouldn't have thermal protection. It may however decide to melt other stuff nearby, such as wire insulation material or hot glue blobs.